# "First steps with Tensorflow", how to access the data files outside of colab?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm Attempting to run "First steps with Tensorflow" locally, outside of colab. Not really familiar with colab so I don't know how to access the "dataframes" such as "california_housing_dataframe", etc. Evidently colab "knows" how to access the dataframes in the example but I am attempting to run the exercise natively on my local system.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have Pandas library locally installed. Then, I think it would run natively.

Comment: Yes, I do have pandas library locally installed. But this is the error that I got when running the code.

ValueError: Could not find trained model in model_dir: /tmp/tmpkjwdhdrd.

I looked in the /tmp/tmpkjwdhdrd directory and , yes, there was nothing there.

Comment: It seems that there is no trained model in the /tmp directory..once you have the trained model..the code will run..you can check this link out..might be of some help to you https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model